# more about binding for radio-button checked (somthing that is not disscussed yet)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, durandal

Two days ago I asked question ["radio button checked binding html5, durandal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384301/radio-button-checked-binding-html5-durandal). I accepted an answer that looked well, but it doesn't work.

I wanted to only add a comment and tell that it doesn't work; but for adding comment I need 50 reps...

**If you want to really help me and you don't want to answer me things that will work in your project but not in my project, you must first read my previous questions, so you will know all of the options that I already tried didn't work.**

So I didn't have another choice but write new question... please don't be angry.

I will tell more about my project, may be it will help you to help me...
I work in DURANDAL project.
I have two radio-buttons, called "searchBy". the first button id is: "byId". the second button id is: "byName". the user have to choose one of them, and I have to know what did he choose.

I tried the code that was written in the document that was attached in the comment, it doesn't work.

That code below:

html code:

```
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="byId" innerHTML:"search by id" />
                                <input type="radio"
                                    name="radSearchBy"
                                    id="byId"
                                    value="RadioById"
                                    data-bind="checked:computedIsId" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="byName" innerHTML:"search by name" />
                                <input type="radio"
                                    name="radSearchBy"
                                    value="RadioByName"
                                    id="byName"
                                   data-bind="checked:computedIsId"
                                   />
                        </td>

                        </tr>
```

javascript behind:

```
                 computedIsId:ko.observable("searchById"),
```

it does not work!!!

---

I tried the code that was written in the first answer, It doesn't either...

javascript behind:

```
                radSearchBy = ko.observable(true);
             value = ko.computed({
               read: function() { return radSearchBy.toString(); },
                    write: function(val) { radSearchBy(val === 'true'); }
                });
```

html code:

```
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="byId" innerHTML:"search by id" />
                                <input type="radio"
                                    name="radSearchBy"
                                    id="byId"                                        
                                    data-bind="value" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="byName" innerHTML:"search by name" />
                                <input type="radio"
                                    name="radSearchBy"
                                    data-bind="value" 
                                    id="byName"

                                   />
                        </td>

                        </tr>
```

I tried also to write in the second button "databind="checked:!value()"", or write else in the first button "()" after the word "value"... nothing help.

can you help me?

Comment: here is a similar problem and look at my answer for how to work with options binding(radio button choices) http://stackoverflow.com/a/19451055/2147987.  Also spend some time on ko tutorials.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384301/radio-button-checked-binding-html5-durandal/19387477#19387477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend helped me, if you want to learn the answer- here is:

you have to add to the radio-buttons property called "value".
now, you have binding the property "checked" to e property behind.
the property behind will be observable.initialize it to one of the strings you gaves at the propery "value" of the radio-butoons.
it is special knockout feature.
when you will change the checking, the property behind will accept the string of the "value" property of the current checked readio.

here is simple example:

```
         <                    input type="radio"
                                    name="radSearchBy"                                      
                                    value="byNo"
                                    data-bind="checked: searchBy" />
                                <label for="byNo" data-bind="text: global.dict()[376]" />

                                <input type="radio"
                                    name="radSearchBy"                                       
                                    value="byName"
                                    data-bind="checked: searchBy" />
```

the javascript behind:
                                var vm = {

```
                                  searchBy: ko.observable("byno"),
                            }
                            return vm;
```

it is more simple then you think...

when you want to know if radio is checked, you have write"

```
                       function isByNo(){

                                     return vm.searchBy() == "byNo" ? true : false;
                        }
```

when you want to check any button from the code you have to write:

```
                       vm.searchBy("byNo");
```